# Django-taggit: can not have all the data with key in tags object

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-taggit

I am trying to achieve my event model with tags object nested with it. But tags have only name field, I need both id, name and slug as well.

here is my Model looks like

`model.py`

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=151, db_index=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    tags = TaggableManager()
serializers.py

class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    slug = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    tags = TagListSerializerField()
```

the Result I am having:

```
{
            "id": 52,
            "slug": "52-aperiam-amet",
            "tags": [
                "hello",
                "world"
            ],
            "title": "Aperiam amet",
            "description": "Quibusdam ipsum sun Quibusdam ipsum sun Quibusdam ipsum sun ",
        },
```

but expected tags nest should look like

```
"tags": [
                {
                   id:"1",
                   slug:'1-hello',
                   name:"hello"
                },
                {
                   id:"2",
                   slug:'2-world',
                   name:"world"
                },
            ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with a `TagSerializer`:

```
from taggit.models import Tag


class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'slug')
```

and then work with:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    slug = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True)
```

That being said, essentially `Taggit` aims to hide the tag model and expose it as just strings, this is likely the main task `django-taggit` aims to achieve, and likely is better since exposing the primary key makes it more complicated.

Comment: also i wish to use another `tag` field but no luck like `audience = TaggableManager()` in the event model. The error is `AudienceTypeTag has no field named 'tag'. The app cache isn't ready yet, so if this is an auto-created related field, it won't be available yet.`

Comment: @Sharif: it is not entirely clear to me what you are trying to do. Can you create a new question with sufficient context (the two (?) models with the `TaggableManager`s etc,)?

Comment: Finally I have removed this package, because its not fulfilling my purpose. I have created own model tag. I have found its overly complex and did not understand the purpose of django-taggit. Many many thanks for your answer and support.